# Mathematica Issue: solving matrix equation AX=\lambdaBX Symbolically

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, equation-solving

I'm new to Mathematica, and I'm trying to solve a matrix equation in a form as

```
AX = \lambda BX
```

Here,  `A`and `B` are  `4*4` matrices in the following, `\lambda` is a value, `X`is the eigenvector- `4*1` matrix.

```
A = {{a1 + b1,  c,  d, f},
     {c,  a2 + b2 , f , e},
     {d , f , a3 + b1 , c},
     { f,  e , c,  a4 + b2}}

B = {{1,  0,  0 , 0},
     {0,  1 , 0 , 0},
     {0 , 0 , -1 , 0},
     {0,  0 , 0,  -1}}
```

I would like to solve this matrix equation and get the symbolical solution for `\lambda` using `a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,c,d,e,f`, etc.

It would be much grateful if anyone can tell me.

Best regards,

mike

Comment: Equations of the form (A-lambda*I)X = 0 are called eigenvalue problems.  If you rearrange yours into that form it might be easier to find a general solution.  Premultiply both sides by B(inverse) and you've got it.

Comment: Thanks, but matrix B is not an identity matrix. And it would be grateful if you can post some commands on mathematica.

Comment: I know B is not an identity matrix; that's precisely why I suggested premultiplying both sides by B(inverse) to get it into the eigenvalue form.  I'm not a Mathematica user, so I can't post commands.

Comment: @duffymo fyi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem

Comment: @ChrisDegnen - thank you.  My experience has been with physics problems like natural frequency and buckling mode calculations, which are usually in form using the identity matrix.  I'm glad to be reminded of the generalized form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Wolfram: Matrix Computations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixComputations.html) - specifically the section 'Generalized Eigenvalues'.

> For *n*×*n* matrices *A*, *B* the generalized eigenvalues are the *n*
>   roots of its characteristic polynomial, *p() = det(A -  B)*. For
>   each generalized eigenvalue, *λ ∊ λ(A, B)*, the vectors, , that
>   satisfy
>
> ***A χ = λ B χ***
>
> are described as generalized eigenvectors.

Example using symbolic values:

```
matA = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}};
matB = {{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}};

Eigenvalues[{matA, matB}]
```

> {(1/(2 (-b12 b21+b11 b22)))(a22 b11-a21 b12-a12 b21+a11 b22-Sqrt[(-a22 b11+a21 b12+a12 b21-a11 b22)^2-4 (-a12 a21+a11 a22) (-b12 b21+b11 b22)]),(1/(2 (-b12 b21+b11 b22)))(a22 b11-a21 b12-a12 b21+a11 b22+Sqrt[(-a22 b11+a21 b12+a12 b21-a11 b22)^2-4 (-a12 a21+a11 a22) (-b12 b21+b11 b22)])}

```
Eigenvectors[{matA, matB}]
```

> ...

Comment: Thanks @Chris . This does help me a lot. For A χ = λ B χ, in Mathematica, I may use Eigenvalues[{A, B}]. Similarly in Matlab, I found to use [V,D]=eig(A,B). Thanks again, cheers.